# I have a border but on the bottom left corner there is no radius

Tags: php, html, css, border

Bottom right, top right and left they all have a perfect radius, but my bottom left one is not "closing".

Here my code:

```
.form_edit{
  border: 1px solid rgb(102, 102, 102);
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
}
```

Comment: its working. here you can see. http://jsbin.com/sabowate/1/edit

Comment: I am confused. So my CSS is correct? But why does it not work on the bottom left corner? On the bottom left there is a little piece outstanding but on the other corners the radius works perfectly.

Comment: might be at bottom left some other div overlapping it..

Comment: your fiddle works OK for me, all the 4 corners are the same.

Comment: it may depend on the **actual element** having class `.form_edit`, that's why I asked **what's `.form_edit`**. Try exacting part of your HTML code so that your problem can be seen and share a fiddle here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine...
Which browser does this get affected in?

Give this a try.

```
.form_edit {
border: 1px solid rgb(102, 102, 102);
background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-khtml-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Comment: It works. My problem was that I had a little image on the bottom left.